# Rotating csvautotabular

Tags: tables, rotating, csv

I'm trying to include a table from an external data document which I have as a .csv file. I'm using

```
\begin{sidewaystable} 
    \begin{table} [H]
    \csvautotabular{nameofcsvfile.csv}
    \end{table}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

to try and get the table in my document but rotate by a 90° angle. I keep getting the error

LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

and I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you don't need the `table` environment. This should work just fine:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
    \csvautotabular{test-table.csv}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, to rotate a table, you can use the `adjustbox` environment from the `adjustbox` package:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=0}
    \csvautotabular{test-table.csv}
\end{adjustbox}


\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
    \csvautotabular{test-table.csv}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped!